# Error: You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run: libXtst.so.6 [...]

Tags: 16.04, 64-bit, steam

I'm aware that many people are having problems on launching Steam (downloaded from Steam not the repos) on Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit with this error message:

```
svetlana@svetlana-desktop:~$ steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Error: You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
libXtst.so.6
libXrandr.so.2
libgobject-2.0.so.0
libglib-2.0.so.0
libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
libpulse.so.0
libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1463778979)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1463778979)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1463778979)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1463778979)
[2016-05-22 16:33:15] Startup - updater built May 20 2016 18:57:58
[2016-05-22 16:33:15] Opted in to client beta 'publicbeta' via beta file
You are in the 'publicbeta' client beta.
Looks like steam didn't shutdown cleanly, scheduling immediate update check
[2016-05-22 16:33:15] Checking for update on startup
[2016-05-22 16:33:15] Checking for available updates...
[2016-05-22 16:33:15] Download skipped by HTTP 304 Not Modified
[2016-05-22 16:33:15] Nothing to do
[2016-05-22 16:33:15] Verifying installation...
[2016-05-22 16:33:15] Performing checksum verification of executable files
[2016-05-22 16:33:15] Verification complete
[2016-05-22 16:33:16] Shutdown
```

My question has anyone found a solution yet?

Comment: I have always installed Steam using `sudo apt install steam`, which will grab all the necessary dependencies on 32-bit libraries. Have you tried that yet?

Comment: @edwinksl Yes, and it still gives the same problem.

Comment: It's the strangest thing... you know what works? $ sudo /usr/games/steam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of the lastest update, they fixed the bug and steam now works again.

Comment: I had to do an update (twice) of steam, then it worked by itself, without me installing anything.

Answer (score 6):

It seems like it can't find a couple static object files, and looking into it, it seems like a couple packages might be missing. Below are the packages and where I found the answer.

libXtst.so.6 - [libxtst6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17355863/cant-find-install-libxtst-so-6)

libXrandr.so.2 - [libxrandr2](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libXrandr.so.2&mode=exactfilename&suite=xenial&arch=any)

libgobject-2.0.so.0 - [libglib2.0-0](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libgobject-2.0.so.0&mode=exactfilename&suite=xenial&arch=any)

libglib-2.0.so.0 - [libglib2.0-0](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libglib-2.0.so.0&mode=exactfilename&suite=xenial&arch=any)

libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 - [libgtk2.0-0](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0&mode=exactfilename&suite=xenial&arch=any)

libpulse.so.0 - [libpulse0](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libpulse.so.0&mode=exactfilename&suite=xenial&arch=any)

libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 - [libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0&mode=exactfilename&suite=xenial&arch=any)

As a one-liner:

```
 sudo apt update && sudo apt install libxtst6 libxrandr2 libglib2.0-0 libgtk2.0-0 libpulse0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0
```

If it still throws that error, then it's not an easy fix and it's probably a problem with Steam. I don't use Steam so I could be wrong on this.

Comment: Nope, didn't help.

Answer (score 5):

steam is a 32bit application, you need the :i386 versions for each package name if you aren't running a 32bit system.

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install libxtst6:i386 libxrandr2:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386 libpulse0:i386 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 -y
```

Comment: This doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the Debian packages to work properly in 2024. In the end, steam would only start with SU permissions:

> sudo /usr/games/steam

Of course, that's no state to work with. Instead, the solution is to get packages from elsewhere:

> flatpak install com.valvesoftware.Steam